# The responsive menu does not work on website

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I code the responsive menu, but it does not work. My expectation: when you click on the hamburger menu, the menu will transform to the close icon, and the full-screen menu is open (background->opacity .5).

I am not sure where is the mistake. CSS? or js? 
Do you have any suggestions? 
Any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let hamburgerClicked = false;

  $('#toggle').on("click", function() {
    if (hamburgerClicked == false) {
      $(".top").css('transform', 'translate (11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg)');
      $(".bottom").css('transform', 'translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg)');

      hamburgerClicked = true;
    } else {
      $(".top").css('transform', 'translate (0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)');
      $(".bottom").css('transform', 'translateY (0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)');
      hamburgerClicked = false;
    }
    $("#overlay").toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.button-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5%;
  right: 2%;
  height: 27px;
  width: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  opacity: 1;
  content: "";
}

.button-container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.top:active {
  transform: translate(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
}

.middle:active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.bottom:active {
  transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
}

span {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 4px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.middle {
  top: 10px;
}

.bottom {
  top: 20px;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 500;
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5%;
  height: 0%;
  opacity: .6;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity .35s, visibility .35s, height .35s;
}

li {
  animation: fadeInRight .5s ease forwards;
  animation-delay: .35s;
}

li:nth-of-type(2) {
  animation-delay: .4s;
}

li:nth-of-type(3) {
  animation-delay: .45s;
}

li:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: .50s;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  height: 70%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

li {
  display: block;
  height: 25%;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a:hover {
  transform: scale(1);
}

a:hover:after,
a:focus:after,
a:active:after {
  width: 30%;
}

a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 0%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  height: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  transition: .35s;
}

@keyframes fadeInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    left: 20%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
  }
}

.active {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stargazing</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you publish it in a live demo? Like in JSFiddle or CodePen

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: html:
 <div class="button-container" id="toggle">
 <span class="top"></span>
 <span class="middle"></span>
 <span class="bottom"></span>
       </div>
  <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
        <ul>
  <li><a href="#constellation">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#what is constellations?">About</a></li>
 <li><a href="#12 constellations">12 Constellations</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Stargazing</a></li>
 </ul>
 </nav>
 </div>

Comment: Click on F12 and show in dev tool if you have any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are mistakes in your Javascript code.

When you are changing the css of .top span, you are using 'translate' instead of 'translateY'.

```
$(".top").css('transform', 'translate (11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg)'); // In if condition
$(".top").css ('transform', 'translate (0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)'); // In else condition
```

This should be:

```
$(".top").css('transform', 'translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg)'); // In if condition
$(".top").css ('transform', 'translateY(0px) translateX(0) rotate(0deg)'); // In else condition
```

Also when clicking on the button you should toggle the visibility of the middle span so that the button looks like a cross.

```
$(".middle").css("display", "none"); // In if condition
$(".middle").css("display", ""); // In else condition
```

Here is a working demo on JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0p9faz7m/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!

I had coded as your suggestion, but it also does not work. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: @Hei.l can you please explain what is not working ?

Comment: it is not active

Comment: @Hei.l What is not active ? can you please provide some more details. Is the JSFiddle demo not correct ?

Comment: It cannot show as the JSFiddle demo do. The menu is just like an icon. The full-screen menu does not show.

Comment: @Hei.l do you mean that it is not working on your machine as it is working on JSFiddle ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have any suggestion? I guess it might be the Javascript code problem, but I am not sure.

Comment: @Hei.l can you show me how you are loading the Javascript on your HTML page ?

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
 <script src="js/fullpage.js"></script>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: @Hei.l are you doing it inside the <head> tag ?

Comment: The scripts in the <head> tag are loaded before the page is rendered. You need to load this script after the page is rendered. In this case the script cannot find the button as it is not yet rendered. Try loading the script before the end of <body> tag and it should work.

Comment: @Hei.l okay i found the problem. <div class="twinkling"></div> This container has z-inder '1' and is on top of the <header> container hence you are not able to click on button. You can fix this by making the z-index of <header> greater than that of the 'twinkling' <div>.

Comment: So I add z-inder:3; on the <header>(CSS). Is it correct?

Comment: The menu is active, but the full-screen menu also doesn't show.

Comment: But it does not work after I upload on the server? 
Link:http://louisasze.com/wnm250/module-15/final/

Comment: @Hei.l have you defined the same script twice ? once in 'main.js' and once in script tag in HTML file ?

Comment: @Hei.l for some reason the .active and .open class are toggled twice on the overlay div when you click on the button. It should toggle only once.

Comment: Is that means I only delete .on on js and it will be work?

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem but it is not good to load same code twice. You can remove the script tag as the code is already loaded from 'main.js'.

Comment: It still does not work on index.html, but the menu can open on other html.

Comment: But I cannot change the text color on the open menu. (section:12 constellation cards)
Here is the link:http://louisasze.com/wnm250/module-15/final/

Comment: And the link is not active. However, I have added <a href="> in html page.

Comment: @Hei.l can you share the project with me so that i can debug properly.

Comment: Sure. How can I share the project with you?

Comment: The file is a bit large.

Comment: @Hei.l create a repository on github

Comment: I have created a repository on github. Link: on https://github.com/Hei-lc/responsive-menu/upload

Comment: @Hei.l i have created a pull request with the fix. You can merge my pull request and then check if it is working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have checked it but the menu is not working on index.html.

Comment: Do my html code is wrong? I have added <a href=""> on html page on the menu, but it does not work. (on other pages) And, I want to change the text color of the menu.  Do I add color=#fff on li or a?

Comment: @Hei.l i have created one more pull request. Please merge it and check again. In <a href="#id"> you need to provide the id of the section you need to scroll to when you click the anchor tag.

Comment: The menu does not show in index.html now. But it is showing on other pages. If I add links on the menu, <a href="index.html>Home</a> Is it correct? On other pages, there is only the menu can go back to index.html. And, I want to specify where will it to go (which section of index.html). e.g., Home-> index.html, section1; About-> index.html, section 2,etc. How to code these?

Comment: The menu does not show in index.html. Is it because of js code? or css?

Comment: you cannot write <a href="index.html"> in other html files as index.html is not present in views folder. You need to go one level up first, so write <a href="../index.html">

Comment: In all places you need to provide the relative path if you need to use an external file. Refer this article : https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: If I want to specify where will it to go (one of the section in index.html). e.g., Home-> index.html, section1; About-> index.html, section 2,etc. How to code these?

Comment: I don't understand, why does the menu is working on other pages, but it only does not work on index.html. They are using the same code in html, css and js.

Comment: to go to one of the sections in index.html you can use <a href="../index.html#section3">

Comment: there is no problem with your js or css, you just need to give the path to the other files correctly.

Comment: @Hei.l i have created one more pull request. This fixes links in other pages.